# Error 0x8007000D when downloading Apps from Windows Store for Business

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

We recently published an update to our app which is deployed in our customers **Windows Store for Business** through developer/partner portal.

Installing or updating the app on customer devices fails. 
The store reports **Something unexpected happend - 0x8007000D** on installing or updating the app on all devices we could test.

We first thought about our app having an issue, but other vendor apps in the store for business also report this issue.

Anyone having the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

After research I narrowed the issue down to certificate/signature.

Here is a very helpful documentation to track down common issues: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/appxpkg/how-to-troubleshoot-app-package-signature-errors

Checking my certificates didn't show an issue so I wondered what could be the issue and came across the Store submission API we are using out of VSTS within our release pipeline, to submit the build appxbundle to the store.

Knowing this I found the following Github issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/windows-dev-center-vsts-extension/issues/58

**Summary:** There was a temporary issue with the store submission API causing the submission to be pending for very long time which let the timestamp of the digital signature somehow diverse. 
After submitting manually through the developer center the issue is gone.

Meanwhile the root issue was solved by the store team and submissions works again.